# Super Saiyan 4 vs Super Saiyan Blue in Dragon Ball Heroes, which transformation is stronger?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-heroes

Super Saiyan 4 vs Super Saiyan Blue is being reported to appear fighting in Dragon Ball Heroes. Dragon Ball Heroes it's an official non-canon Dragon Ball videogame and manga. Which transformation is stronger?

Note: Before marking the topic as "opinion-based" notice most transformations in Dragon Ball are officially ranked in order of power through the anime, manga, and official guides and websites.

(with the exceptions of Super Saiyan Rage and Legendary Super Saiyan / Super Saiyan Berserker that nobody can assure exactly where they are)

(Oozaru < SSJ1 < SSJ2 < SSJ3 < SSG < SSB / SSRosé < UI)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Japan, the *Dragon Ball Heroes* website did a poll on who fans thought were the strongest characters and forms in the game. You can view the same [here](http://www.carddass.com/dbh/event/strongest_dbh_lineup/index.php). As per the source, SSJB Goku is considered to be the **third** strongest character in the game while SSJ4 Goku is considered to be the **ninth** strongest character. SSJB Vegeta is considered to be the **eleventh** strongest character while SSJ4 Vegeta is the **seventeenth** strongest character on the game. So based on  *the poll only* SSJB is > SSJ4.

However, certain characters in the anime like Whis , Beerus and even Omega Shenron, who are clearly superior to SSJB/SSJ4(In Super, GT) Are a lot lower down the list(Even below Yamcha). So there isn't really a perfect answer to your question.

## Final List

- Time Breaker Bardock
- SSJ4 GT Gogeta
- SSJB Goku
- LSSJ4 Broly
- Darkness Towa
- SSJ3 Time Patrol Bardock
- Tarble
- SSJ4 GT Gohan
- SSJ4 GT Goku
- Super 17 (18 Absorbed)
- SSJB Vegeta
- Super Mira
- Golden Frieza
- LSSJ Broly
- SSJ3 Vegetto
- Majuub
- SSJ4 GT Vegeta
- Towa
- SSJ2 Teen Gohan
- SSJG Goku
- Yamcha
- Supreme Kai of Time
- Syn Shenron
- Whis
- Runaway Mira
- Amond
- Resurrected Dabura
- LSSJ3 Broly
- Omega Shenron
- Angered Beerus

Comment: I only see listed 1 to 8. How about super saiyan god? Where is it listed?

Comment: I updated the answer with the list.

Comment: This question might have a new answer soon since it's being announced that in the new Dragon Ball Heroes anime there is going to be a fight between SSJ4 vs SSBlue. Just update the post when it happens and I'll keep the answer marked as accepted.

Comment: I think it should be a separate question just like in case of xenoverse,  the level of strength of Xenoverse Characters is obviously different from those in the anime.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be all different in the different medias. 
In the videogame it seems to be as already posted in the other answer. 
In the manga Super Saiyan 4 Goku Xeno and Super Saiyan Blue Goku seem to be even, even though Goku Xeno seems to be surprised by the Super Saiyan Blue.

And in the anime, we see

> When Super Saiyan Blue Kaiokenx50 Vegito had an even fight with Cumber base form, Super Saiyan 4 Xeno Vegito seems to be stronger than Super Saiyan 3 Cumber. That would make Super Saiyan 4 way stronger than Super Saiyan Blue in the Dragon Ball Heroes anime